# How does the foreach iteration happen for two dimensional System.Array?

Tags: c#

Suppose we are creating a System.Array as

```
      Array _twoD = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), 2,2);


        _twoD.SetValue("Harrish", 0, 0);
        _twoD.SetValue("Goel", 0, 1);
        _twoD.SetValue("Prakash", 1, 0);
        _twoD.SetValue("Manish", 1, 1);
        foreach (string str in _twoD)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
```

How does the Enumerator automatically iterates [0,0] [0,1] ,[1,0] ,[1,1] ?

**[For single simensional array,it is easy to understand,what is internally happen in 2D and 3 D ? ]**

Can we create Jagged Style array using System.Array ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(VS.71).aspx)

> The System.Array type (Section 12.1.1)
>   is a collection type, and since all
>   array types derive from System.Array,
>   any array type expression is permitted
>   in a foreach statement. The order in
>   which foreach traverses the elements
>   of an array is as follows: For
>   single-dimensional arrays, elements
>   are traversed in increasing index
>   order, starting with index 0 and
>   ending with index Length – 1. **For
>   multi-dimensional arrays, elements are
>   traversed such that the indices of the
>   rightmost dimension are increased
>   first, then the next left dimension,
>   and so on to the left.**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will go [0, 0], [0, 1] etc. You can see this more easily by creating a 2D array directly in C# with `new string[2,2]`.

As a demo:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[,] strings = new string[2,2];
        // Just to make things absolutely explict
        strings[0,0] = "0,0";
        strings[0,1] = "0,1";
        strings[1,0] = "1,0";
        strings[1,1] = "1,1";

        foreach (string x in strings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0,0
0,1
1,0
1,1
```

Creating a jagged array with `System.Array` is just a case of creating an array with an element type of `string[]` etc. A jagged array is simply an array of arrays.

Comment: Jon Skeet.Quite familiar name. Are u authoring C# in depth for manning ?

Answer (score 2):

For enumerating jagged arrays, `SelectMany` (LINQ) is your friend:

```
    int[][] data = { new int[] {0,1,2},
                       new int[] {3,4},
                       new int[] {5,6,7,8}};
    foreach (int i in data.SelectMany(row => row))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

Or in query syntax:

```
    int[][] data = { new int[] {0,1,2},
                       new int[] {3,4},
                       new int[] {5,6,7,8}};
    foreach (int i in from row in data
                      from cell in row
                      select cell)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The array is enumerated row by row, then column by column

```
        var array = new[,]{
            {"A1","A2","A3"},
            {"B1","B2","B3"}
        };

        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Displays :

> A1
>
> A2
>
> A3
>
> B1
>
> B2
>
> B3

Regarding your second question :

> Can we create Jagged Style array using System.Array ?

Not directly. A jagged array is an array of arrays, so you would have to write something like that :

```
        Array array = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int[]), 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array.SetValue(Array.Create(typeof(int) 3), i);
        }
```